# RestTemplate vs. OpenFeign. OpenFeign is it just a possibile alternative to RestTemplate or exist use cases where it have do be used?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, openfeign

as a Spring developer I always used SpringTemplate in order to perform REST call. Today studying on a Udemy course about micro services implementation using Spring Boot I discovered this Open Feign.

I understood that it have a declarative style and that it is pretty easy to use and that it seems to me that using it the writted code is reduced...but it is not clear to me if it is simply a possible alternative to the use of the classic RestTemplate or if there are specific use cases where it must be used instead RestTemplate (or when it is better use this Open Feign instead RestTemplate).

What do you think about it?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Spring Cloud OpenFeign](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-openfeign) to find an official integration of OpenFeign into Spring Boot applications.

Didn't find out yet if it is usable with plain Spring Framework.